# How to get text from Authentication window in Browsers

Tags: selenium, autoit

[image]

To fill Authentication Pop-up, I want get server name displayed in the Authentication Pop-up. So that I can determine which user name and password I have to use. Please guide how to get Highlighted text in the attached image.

I tried with below statements but it did not work.

ControlGetText ( "Authentication Required", "", "[INSTANCE:1]")\

WinGetText ( "Authentication Required")

Comment: Are you using IE? AutoIT works best with IE (at detecting objects). If not, then you have to use the web page title. For example, `Google` for https://www.google.co.in/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can NOT auth with this window. But you can auth without getting this window. Try change URL to:
     http://user:password@www.yourserveradress.com

if this will not help, you need to create separated profile in browser, pass authentification on this server and remember password and use this profile in selenium.